# Make request using https not http using Rails intridea/omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

How do you configure the Rails intridea/omniauth gem to make a HTTPS request when authenticating (using localhost)?

Is it in the specific strategy (fb, linkedin, pinterest, etc) or do I do it in the middleware config or someplace else(config/application.rb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure this in the `OmniAuth::Builder` configuration, through the `client_options` parameter.

> You can configure custom endpoints via `client_options` hash passed to `provider`.

From the documentation for [omniauth-facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#api-version).

**Example:**

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV["APP_ID"], ENV["APP_SECRET"],
    client_options: {
      site: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0",
      authorize_url: "https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth"
    }
end
```